# How do I run python script with runpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, runpy

I am trying to run a python script and I wanted d to run it with a more pythonic way rather than maybe calling `subprocess.run()`.

I found the `runpy` library and I am trying to call my script like this:

```
runpy.run_path(path_name='/home/dir1/dr2/dr3/run_code.py', run_name='__main__')
```

This returns me and error that one of the modules used in the `run_code.py` does not exist:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fluent_logger'
```

When I run the same script with `subprocess.run()` I get no errors.

Am I using this the wrong way?

Comment: Please post the full error message

Comment: @Mortz added it

Comment: And is `fluent_logger` a module defined by you or an installed library?

Comment: @Mortz our module, just another file in the same directory